# "assignment to entry in nil map" with simple interface assignment not working

Tags: go, interface

I try to get myself familiarise with `interface{}` in Go. I tried:

```
         var  m  map[string]string
         m["time"] = "asdf"
```

and get error:

> assignment to entry in nil map

I am not sure why I get the error.

Comment: 1. Your error means that you're trying to assign to a nil map. `m` is a nil map, because you have not assigned any value to it. Google for that error, and you'll find countless explanations of the fix. 2. There are no interfaces in your code or the question, so the title doesn't make sense.

Comment: when a variable is declared without you adding a value to it, it has a default value. In you your case, the default value of map is nil. Check this link out on default values for all Go types.
https://yourbasic.org/golang/default-zero-value/

Comment: m := map[string]string{}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable like this:

```
var  m  map[string]string
```

your `m` variable is assigned with a default value of `map`, which is `nil`, not an empty map. This is why you get that error, you are trying to add a value to a nil map.

To initialize an empty map, you can try any of these:

```
var m map[string]string = map[string]string{}
m := make(map[string]string)
m := map[string]string{}
```

[Here](https://yourbasic.org/golang/default-zero-value/) is an article on default values for all Go types.

Answer (score 0):

The value of map m is nil.

The make function allocates and initializes a hash map data structure and returns a map value that points to it.

```
m := make(map[string]string)
m["time"] = "asdf"
```

Read [allocations with make](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_make) section of specs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use make(built-in function) like
`make(map[string]string, 0)`
to initialize the map

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_make
https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps